# Next/Previous Page bug

Tags: php

I need some help, I want to make an next / previous page but I have some problems...

This is the PHP Code, how I try to make it. The problem is that it doesn't show 3 data on the first page and on the next page it puts the same data again an not the other one.

Code:

```
$statement = $connect->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS anzahl FROM `accounts`");
$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch();
$max_data = $row['anzahl'];

$page = 1;
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
   $page = intval($_GET['page']);
}

$max_info = 3;
$start = ($page - 1) * $max_info;
$number_page = ceil($max_data / floatval($max_info));    

for($a = 1; $a <= $anzahl_seiten; $a++) {
   if($page == $a){
      echo " <b>$a</b> ";
   } 
   else {  
      echo " <a href='acp.php?page=list_all_player&seite=$a'>$a</a> ";
   }
```

}

Comment: I know where is the problem!
This php code is right but the other mysql statement where I get the Data Informations I have to put the Limit into!

It works now

Comment: Can you write: what result do you want to get. And what do you actually get?

Comment: I have to write this in the other statement "$query      =   $connect->prepare("SELECT `id`, `name`, `level`, `admin` FROM `accounts` LIMIT :start, :limit");" I've forgot the Limit ^^